# How to make folder accessable through web (like "Content" folder)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to make folder (from solution) visible through web browser using Visual Studio 2013, ASP.Net MVC?

I want to create some kind of detached folder for some JS files that have to be accessable by URL.

Comment: You don't want write access, just read access? Did you try adjusting the permissions appropriately?

Comment: @mason: only read access. Where can I adjust those permissions?

Comment: I believe by default they do have permissions. Have you tried accessing them? What is the result?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Right click->Add Folder
2. Right click on the folder -> Add New Item
3. HTML Page

I didn't have to do anything further for read-only access.

(In your case you'd probably want to Add Existing Item.)